# If $c_{n} > 0$ then $\sum_{0}^{n}c_{k}x^{k} > 0$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: polynomials

Let $n \geq 1$ be an integer and let $c_{0}, \dots, c_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$. If $c_{n} > 0,$ is there necessarily an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$\sum_{0}^{n}c_{k}x^{k} > 0?$$

I just realized that for a while I had implicitly taken this for granted. However, when I would like to give a rigorous proof then I find it is not that obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Any $x > \frac{|c_{n-1}|+|c_{n-2}|+...+|c_0|}{c_n}+1$ works.

This implies that $x>1$ and in particular 
$$c_nx^n > |c_{n-1}|x^{n-1}+|c_{n-2}|x^{n-1}+...+|c_0|x^{n-1} \geq |c_{n-1}|x^{n-1}+|c_{n-2}|x^{n-2}+...+|c_0| \\ \geq -c_{n-1}x^{n-1}-c_{n-2}x^{n-2}-...-c_0  $$

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I fail to see how the implication leads to the desired statement. What if every $c_{k}\ (k=1, \dots, n-1)$ is $< 0$?

Comment: @YLChou Fixed, I forgot to put the minuses on the last one ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Suppose $x>0$ and consider $f(x) = {\sum_{k=0}^n c_k x^k \over x^n} = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k {1 \over x^{n-k}}$. Then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = c_n>0$, hence there is some $M$ such that if $x \ge M$, then $f(x) >0$. Hence
${\sum_{k=0}^n c_k x^k } >0$ for $x \ge M$.